# Linked list prints extra 0 at the beginning

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc, singly-linked-list

I have a very basic singly linked list implementation. The problem with my implementation, however, is it prints an extra zero at the beginning of the list whereas I am not explicitly allocating any storage for this extra node. Code for the same is as below -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define LEN 7

/* List node data structure */
typedef struct _ll_node_ {
    int data;
    struct _ll_node_ *next;
} node;

/*
 * @brief   Utility to print the state of the list
 */
void print_list(node *head)
{
    int i = 0;
    node *tmp = head;
    while (tmp)
    {
        printf("Node:\t%d,\tValue:\t%d\n", ++i, tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
 * @brief   Utility to add nodes to the list
 */
node *add_node(node *head, int data)
{
    node *tmp;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        assert(head != NULL);
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        assert(tmp->next != NULL);
        tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}

/*
 * @brief   Driver function
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    /* Allocate memory */
    head = malloc(LEN * sizeof(node));
    assert(head != NULL);
    /* Populate the list */
    for (; i < LEN; i++)
        head = add_node(head, rand() % 1000);
    /* Print its state */
    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out where I am doing it wrong?

```
System information:
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
    Release:        14.04
    Codename:       trusty
```

Comment: Comment these two lines `head = malloc(LEN * sizeof(node));
    assert(head != NULL);` and rest everything is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement

```
head = malloc(LEN * sizeof(node));
```

does not make sense. Remove it.

You allocated uninitialized array. So using the function add_node results in undefined behaviuor.

Take into account that function `add_node` could be written simpler if to pass the head by reference. For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LEN 7

/* List node data structure */
typedef struct _ll_node_ {
    int data;
    struct _ll_node_ *next;
} node;

/*
 * @brief   Utility to print the state of the list
 */
void print_list(node *head)
{
    int i = 0;
    node *tmp = head;
    while (tmp)
    {
        printf("Node:\t%d,\tValue:\t%d\n", ++i, tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
 * @brief   Utility to add nodes to the list
 */
int add_node( node **head, int data )
{
    int success;

    while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

    *head = malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    success = *head != NULL;

    if (success )
    {
        ( *head )->data = data;
        ( *head )->next = NULL;
    }

    return success;
}

/*
 * @brief   Driver function
 */
int main( void )
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    /* Populate the list */
    for ( ; i < LEN; i++ )
        add_node( &head, rand() % 1000);
    /* Print its state */
    print_list( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are already allocating memory to head in main and hence the first node is never assigned the data and hence by default it takes it to be 0. 
Try this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    /* Populate the list */
    for (; i < LEN; i++)
        head = add_node(head, rand() % 1000);
    /* Print its state */
    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @vlad-from-moscow and priyansh-goel for pointing it out.Totally missed it.

Comment: @rurtle : The better way to thank is to accept the answer.

Comment: @rurtle : I am not desperate for points on SO. Any answer which works for you should be accepted. I don't mind if you accept Vlad's answer. :) Its just that you should always accept an answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: @rurtle : Thank you for accepting Vlad's answer. I am happy atleast you did.